# Read complex JSON data in ReactJS from a file gives undefine error

Tags: reactjs, json

I am reading data from files, I am calling third party services and saving data in files.
Below is one of the sample file actual file is quite large I cut short it,

```
{
    "tag": "#8GYVRVG",
    "name": "Warrior",
    "expLevel": 13,
    "trophies": 5634,
    "bestTrophies": 6007,
    "wins": 7756,
    "clan": {
      "tag": "#9LCLRC90",
      "name": "Herakles",
      "badgeId": 16000177
    },
    "arena": {
      "id": 54000014,
      "name": "Challenger III"
    },
    "badges": [
      {
        "name": "1000Wins",
        "progress": 7756
      },
      {
        "name": "Played1Year",
        "progress": 1464
      }
   ]
}
```

Below is my react function,

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function PlayerData(){
    const [Player,setPlayer] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('../data/player.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => setPlayer(data));
    },[setPlayer]);
return(
    <div>
        <h4>{Player.name}</h4>
        <p>{Player.clan.name}</p>
        {(player.badges || []).map((item)=>{
            <p>{item.name}</p>
        })}
    </div>
);
}
```

while running the code it gives below error,

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

while ready Player.clan.name it throws error. I think render happen before the value gets read. I am not sure how to read data which are not part of array in the file.

Comment: Try to do console.log(data) are you getting whole json file or undefined ?

Comment: I tried that JSON I got. When I do Player.name it show the player name. But on the next line its nested Player.clan.name it throws error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending so much time, below is the solution I find out. As I mentioned the JSON file I received contains key value and array. And what I find out that reading Key Value throws error because render happened first and in nested values I got the undefined error.
To solve this I use two techniques, one I add SetTimeOut in fetch method and second for nested key value I add condition.
Here is the code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function PlayerData(){
    const [Player,setPlayer] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('../data/player.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setPlayer(data);
                }, 200);
                
            });
    },[]);
return(
    <div>
        <h4>{Player.name}</h4>
        <p>{Player.clan && Player.clan.name}</p>
        {(player.badges || []).map((item)=>{
            <p>{item.name}</p>
        })}
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it won't solve everything, but here are three changes which should make it better at least :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
export default function PlayerData(){
  const [player,setPlayer] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('../data/player.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setPlayer(data));
  },[player]);
  return(
    <div>
      <h4>{Player.name}</h4>
      <p>{Player.clan.name}</p>
      {(player.badges || []).map((item)=>{
        return <p>{item.name}</p>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Its not making any effect. even I put await and async to fetch